# Генерация XML Vector при рисовании на экране

Tags: android, xml, android-sdk

Имеются ли какие-нибудь средства для генерации XML Vector на основе действий пользотеля? Основную сложность представляет собой, конечно же, генерация `pathData`:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24"
    android:viewportHeight="24">
    <path android:fillColor="#000" android:pathData="..." />
</vector>
```

Задача такова: сделать рисунок, сделанный в графическом редакторе (например, [в таком](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-create-a-drawing-app-essential-functionality--mobile-19328)) доступным для последующего редактирования. В предложенном по ссылке выше уроке показано только сохранение в bitmap. Я также узнал, что то, что мы нарисовали, уже является растровым изображением, и конвертировать это в вектор невозможно. Стало быть, нужно генерировать pathData во время рисования.

Comment: Если Вас устраивает ответ, пожалуйста отметьте его , как решенный вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Коротко**

Рисуйте сразу в векторном редакторе, например в [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/), далее после сохранения файла в формате *.svg, необходимо найти строку `<path d="M234/.. "`
и скопировать её содержание, начиная с символа **`M`** в `android:pathData="..."` в любом текстовом редакторе.

**Более подробно**

1. При создании векторного рисунка в Inkscape добавляется много служебной информации. Её можно удалить с помощью онлайновой утилиты [SVGOMG](http://petercollingridge.appspot.com/svg-editor) от Jake Archibald.
2. Вы можете не увидеть векторного рисунка в андроид приложении, так как надо правильно прописать viewport и viewBox из SVG файла в файл VectorDrawable.
   Дело в том, что разработчики несколько запутали и обозвали **viewBox** SVG **viewport**,ом VectorDrawable.
   Итак, берете соответственно из SVG файла, допустим `width="24" height="24"` и
   подставляете

`android:width="24dp"`    `android:height="24dp"`

Берете из SVG файла значение двух последних атрибутов `viewBox="0 0 24 24"` и подставляете в файл VectorDrawable -

```
`android:viewportWidth="24"     android:viewportHeight="24"`
```

**Нюансы стилизации**

В отличии от SVG, VectorDrawable не может иметь градиентную заливку — только определенный цвет.

Укажите цвет строки и при желании толщину строки - `android:strokeColor`, `android:strokeWidth`

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ!